# number keypad not working regularly

Tags: 11.04, kernel, keyboard

I have a Toshiba laptop , have full numbatic keypad on the right, can't use it anymore. 8,6,4,2 working like Mouse Arrow.

i tried to enable/disable it but still same .

how can I fix it ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 11.04, open your keyboard preferences and select the "Mouse Keys" tab. Make sure that "Pointer can be controlled using the keypad" is unselected.

Answer (score 1):

That's close.  On 11.11, for me, it was "Univeral Access" -> "Pointing and Clicking" -> "Mouse Keys".  Disabling that, corrected the num-pad-being-used-as-a-mouse-arrow-movement issue.